# Ignore submenu with :not when styling <li>

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that contains a drop-down menu. I want to target the last child in the main menu, which I would normally do with `li:last-child`, however, in this case, the drop-down menu is also a `ul` with `li` inside, creating the following problem:

[image]

I added a class to the 2nd `ul` and tried to ignore the drop-down menu by using `:not(.sub-menu)`. The style is still applied though.

[HERE'S A WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u73t06oa/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>point1</li>
    <li>point2</li>
    <li>point3</li>
    <li>
        point4
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>point4.1</li>
            <li>point4.2</li>
            <li>point4.3</li>
            <li>point4.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>point5</li>
    <li>point6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    background: lightgrey;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    background: skyblue;
}

ul:not(.sub-menu) li:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```

I really expected I the `:not(.sub-menu)` would make sure only the last child of the main menu was targeted, but I might not exactly understand how `:not()` works.

Comment: You use `:not(.sub-menu)` in wrong element, it will apply for `ul` not `li`. It must be `ul li:last-child:not(.sub-menu)` with `.sub-menu` in the last children li. Or you can use `child selector >` like this `ul > li:last-child`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're selecting `ul` which is not having `.sub-menu` class. But the `li`s inside the `.sub-menu` are also the descendants of the outer `ul`. So, your selector will also select the nested `li`.

To solve this, use children selector `>` to select only the direct children of `ul`.

```
ul:not(.sub-menu) > li:last-child {
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o1gq94s6/2/)

```css
ul {
  background: lightgrey;
}
ul.sub-menu {
  background: skyblue;
}
ul:not(.sub-menu) > li:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>point1</li>
  <li>point2</li>
  <li>point3</li>
  <li>
    point4
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>point4.1</li>
      <li>point4.2</li>
      <li>point4.3</li>
      <li>point4.4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>point5</li>
  <li>point6</li>
</ul>
```